# Accessing formgroup in child component from parent component

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to access the multiple formGroup placed inside a component from a  component in parent component

```
@Component({
selector:'parent',
template:'<child1></child1>
<child2></child2>'
})

@Component({
selector:'child1',
template:'<div class="errors"></div>' //Need access to form1 and form2 in 
 this component
})

@Component({
selector:'child2',
template:'<form [formGroup]="form1"</form>
 <form [formGroup]="form2"</form>'
})
```

I need to access the forms in 'child2' component in 'child1' to get the validation errors

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would create the form in parent.  then you can inject FormGroupDirective in the child components.

```
constructor(private fd: FormGroupDirective){}
```

the form would be `this.fd.form`